# JSON data in dash DataTable invalid argument

Tags: python, json, datatable, plotly-dash

I'm trying to display my data into a Dash DataTable but i've got this error:

`` Invalid argument `data` passed into DataTable.
Expected an array.
Was supplied type `object`. ``

My data (amazon comments) :

```
[
{
    "ratings": {
        "\n            5 star\n          ": "\n          ",
        "\n            4 star\n          ": "\n          ",
        "\n            3 star\n          ": "\n          ",
        "\n            2 star\n          ": "\n          ",
        "\n            1 star\n          ": "\n          "
    },
    "reviews": [
        {
            "review_text": "The \"MPD Digital (TM) USA Made Ham CB Radio GMRS Repeater Transmission MILSPEC M17/ 163A RG-213/U (RG8/U) Coaxial Cable with UHF PL259 Connectors, 12 inches \", I having two products of like nature from MPD, the older of the two being lightly used between transmitter and SWR meter,... to being placed in storage when not in use, is a disappointing, if not marginal product given the high level of promoting by MPD (Times Microwave) relative to product component selection, product design, to manufacturing processes and procedures. i) The advertised description for this coax cable is a contradiction. This RF related product is either an RG-213/U or RG-8/U and not both types of RF transmission cable simultaneously. When measured at 50MHz, the Velocity of Propagation (VP) for Foam High Density Polyethylene (FHDPE) dielectric RG-213/U is 66% with 1.5dB loss/100ft where as FHDPE dielectric RG-8/U, the VP is 85% with 1.2dB loss/100ft. ii) The cable ends do not use high grade Amphenol, PL-259 connectors as they did in the past for this product line, the MPD cable received most recently from Kimberly Distribution, being produced with cheap and short (function of cost reducing engineering to basic disrespect, presuming the end user will not know the difference), Chinese made PL-259 connectors (see photo) and per such, have a smaller mating surface with the coax cable, thus less robust attachment. iii) The cable markings for product type, e.g. RG-213/U, are not of a permanent nature, the printing being neither molded into the cable outer jacket or laser burned, the label wearing off with ease from cleaning or use (see photo). Because of such low persistent printing method, less I check the purchase order or some other user is tasked, cannot properly determine with any great assurance, cable type (RF properties), thus VP (velocity of propagation), signal loss, SWR,... As a side note, since the printing on the outer jacket of the coax cable is easy to remove (not permanent), leaving no other identifiers present (mystery cable), that this electrical product maybe considered contraband per contract, code and insurance underwriters for applications in which UL standards compliant electrical components e.g. DoD, Hospitals, Schools, Civil Defense, Fire and Police,... are required or mandated. iv) The 12\" inch (1' ft) coax cables by MPD (Times Microwave) from current to past are not consistent in overall length as seen from simple side by side compassion (see photo and arrogantly rotated by disrespectful Amazon). There seeming to be some manufacturing (procedural and process controls) confusion at MPD relative to how to make consistent measurements (cuts) of the product e.g. is the coax conductor measured to 12\" or the entire path length (connector end point to connector end point) is measured to 12\". The MPD (Time Microwave) cable with contradicting advertising along with low end build quality is an indication that the leadership at MPD has prioritized cutting corners on raw component selection and manufacturing methods for the sake of cost reduction and or higher margins and earnings, as appose to being driven to manufacture a high end and excellent analytical product for discriminating customers. Remember: \"do a job, big or small, do it right, or not at all\". Less processes and procedures are adjusted and rigorously adhered to by Times Microwave (MPD), do not recommend this coax cable, from contradicting description thus EE (Electrical Engineering) properties, to raw component selection thus ultimately integrated build quality to product assurance and type, for demanding and disciplined RF applications. Minus 0.25 for inconsistent process and procedure for measuring total cable path length. Minus 0.25 for contradicting product description, thus electrical (RF) properties of the coax cable. Minus 0.50 for using Chinese made PL-259 connectors rather than high grade Amphenol connectors like in the past. Minus 1.0 for having easy to remove, non permanent type markings (printing) on the transmission coax cable jacket. Park McGraw JPL, Spacecraft Soldering Course Certified Experimental Physicist, Former US Navy, NASA Fellow Former CEO Class C Electrical Contracting Firm, Life Safety Industry Former Instructor, Basic Electricity and Electronics, University of Hawai`i Hilo Former Member Technical Staff and Process Engineering Mgr, Laser and Sensor Products Center, Northrop Grumman (Space Park)",
            "review_posted_date": None,
            "review_header": "Uses Chinese Made PL-259 Connectors, Cable Type Printing Wears Off Easily, Contradicting Description",
            "review_rating": "3.0 ",
            "review_author": "Directed Energy"
        },
        {
            "review_text": "I ordered this coax for Amateur Radio use. RG-213 is rugged coax, much better than many of the air dielectric cables which are actually somewhat fragile. It is double shielded. The connectors are first quality and their installation appears first class. The price is very competitive. I have no connection with browning but I have come to respect their quality products and the value they provide. I have several of their antenna mounts and they are by far the best I have ever seen. In my 40+ years as a ham I learned long ago you buy the best because it lasts. I will confirm the specs on the cable and post any issues here when I get a chance, but I can tell from the packaging, connected quality, weight, and feel the manufacturer intended to deliver a first class product and spared no expense in doing so. I have bought other coax on Amazon but this was the most impressive so far re packaging. I never buy coax on ebay, been burned too often. This piece is intended to allow me to run my qrp cw rig by the pool but I may someday want to run higher power or use it for another antenna run to the shack. I probably own 3000 feet of coax installed at various sites but had none to spare nearby, so it was either gas or coax. The coax arrived in a sturdy box, it was sealed in moisture proof plastic bagging, and uniformly coiled and bound with quality cable ties. It's obvious the manufacturer takes good care of their inventory and this assembly is not made in someone's garage! W7CCE",
            "review_posted_date": None,
            "review_header": "Excellent quality coax, connectors",
            "review_rating": "5.0 ",
            "review_author": "Merciless"
        },
        {
            "review_text": "The coax was working well for six months or so. When I recently unscrewed the PL-259 from my radio, the entire connector came off the coax. The crimp sleeve slid off and the center conductor came completely out of the connector. There was solder on the inner pin of the connector, but it never reached the wire itself, so only the crimp sleeve was holding the wire in, and apparently the crimp sleeve wasn't crimped very well.",
            "review_posted_date": None,
            "review_header": "Connector Failed",
            "review_rating": "1.0 ",
            "review_author": "RichG"
        }
    ],
    "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/product-reviews/B00Y7H39IW/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=14",
    "name": "MPD Digital USA Made Ham CB Radio GMRS Repeater Transmission MILSPEC M17/ 163A RG-213/U (RG8/U) Coaxial Cable with Soldered Silver UHF PL-259 Connectors, 12 inches",
    "price": "$14.99"
}]
```

My code :

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '20%',
            'height': '40px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])
def update_output(contents, filename):
        .
        .
        .
dt = pd.DataFrame(data_extract)
    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            style_data={
                'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                'height': 'auto'
            },
            data=dt.to_dict('list'),
            columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in dt.columns]
        )
    ])

@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
          [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
          [State('upload-data', 'filename')])
def parse_contents(list_of_contents, list_of_names):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            update_output(c, n) for c, n in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)]
        return children


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I upload a csv file to generate the `data_extract` in the update_output() function which i want to display in my DataTable. 
I convert my data_extract into a pandas DataFrame, then i try to submit my data with data=dt.to_dict('list'). I also tried with different argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you only need the `review` part of the data? If so, and `dt` is that part of the json, you can use

```
data=dt.to_dict('records'),
```

because your structure is `[{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]`, see [pandas reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)